# Python argparse, how to make a single word in a help italics

Tags: python, argparse, italic, helpfile

```
mm_add_all_parser.add_argument('run_folder', help='The folder that houses the assets and events folders. The folder structure and file names must be specific. The run_folder \e[4mshould\e[0m be titled with the format')
```

In the above argparse statement, I want the word "should" to be in *italics*. But the console escape characters I'm trying in this statement seem to be ignored by argparse.

Thanks.

Comment: `argparse` is just `printing` that help line.  What you see in the `help` is the same as you get with `print(<that help string>)`.  It's the console that isn't showing italics.

Comment: hmmm... not 100% sure about that. I noticed that "\n" gets stripped out of the help when there, so I don't think it's just echoing raw text to the console because the above solution should work in that case.

Comment: The default formatter does rework the line wrapping.  You have to use a `RAW` formatter to preserve newlines.

Comment: Does it print the escape sequences or are they not shown? The italic is not a default escape sequence so maybe it's not supported. Also if italic is supported it is '\e[3m'.

Comment: Doesn't print anything different than if it wasn't there, as if they are stripped. I guess the question has no appropriate answer without jerry rigging, which isn't worth it.